# How to stop TimeOut in JSX

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, jsx

I have a button that on click calls a function.
In this function there is a for loop which is timed out, this way:

```
for (let i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
      setTimeout( () => { ... }, ANIMATION_SPEED);
}
```

I would like to be able to stop this timeout, and the animation that is created with it, on click of another button.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you save the return value of the function

You can use it to stop her

```
const timeOut = setTimeout(function, milliseconds);

clearTimeout(timeOut);
```

you can save all timeout on an array

```
const timeouts = [];

timeouts.push( setTimeout(function, milliseconds));
```

Then when you want to clear them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++) {
    clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
}
//clear array
timeouts = [];
```

An example that works with useRef

```
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const id = React.useRef([]);

  const clearSetTimeout = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      clearTimeout(id.current[i]);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
//here add time out
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      id.current[i] = setTimeout(() => {
        setCount((c) => c + 1);
      }, 2500);
    }
    return clearSetTimeout;
  }, []);
```

[image: Edit new]

Comment: Thank you. But how can I do this if it's from two different functions? Like if I declare const "timeout" in one function, how can I use it into another function?

Comment: You can use ``React.useRef()``
Do you know it?

Comment: you can see here an example with ``useRef``
https://codesandbox.io/s/persistent-react-state-forked-buukt?file=/src/App.js:50-569

Comment: Hi, I tried everything but nothing seems to work. Even if I do "clearTimeout(timeout)", from anywhere in the code, the animation continues to show on the website. I really don't know what do to. It's like when the for loop and animation start, there is no way to end them before they're done. Any advice?